# write dataframe to existing excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have the below code to set up a worksheet in which i am using xlsxwriter to create a report

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(f'{FUNDNAME}.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Summary')
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Data')
```

all my code works fine up until trying to write a pandas dataframe to the tab "Data"

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{FUNDNAME}.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Data')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

but when I open the file, the tab "Data" is blank.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you saving the changes to `workbook` in the first codeblock?

Comment: I just tried doing that it says "Workbook object doesn't have attribute 'save'"

Comment: Try `.close()`ing the workbook before writing with pandas.

Comment: closing the workbook before writing the pandas seems to overwrite my file that i created with xlsxwriter.  It does write the correct dataframe but I need it to show up on the second tab  of the code that was executed prior using xlsxwriter.  Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: According to https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html you need to specify xlsxwriter as your engine in Pandas so `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`